# How to Import the data from an excel sheet to the MySQL table AUTOMATICALLY?

Tags: excel, import, export, mysql

I got a requirement to develop a Java app to load the data from an excel sheet to a MySQL database table everyday.

My actual requirement is when ever the user opens the application, it should automatically load the data from Excel -> MySQL database table.

I do not have idea to import the data from excel to MySQL table.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the data from excel using MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command..

For automation you have to write a function to run the MySQL command on load..

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. But it is working only for csv. not for xlsx. what do i need to modify in the code to make it to work for xlsx files?

Comment: Just add the columns and lines delimiter in load data infile command for xlxs

Comment: What can be the values of FIELDS TERMINATED BY and OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY for xlsx source?

Comment: You can try:
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\'

Comment: I have uploaded the file and the data screenshot in the below. Could you please check. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5G7Y9UP5Vi3fmpUbmFBcTVobEZSZFdmRUxSYVktaHBNQW0wcVpZMGNtVWV3dk9iT0tSQTQ&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummyTable for daily load

Clear it before you begin

Save your excel in same column structure 
as dummyTable in csv format, comma delimited

Run:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/theFile1.csv' 
INTO TABLE dummyTable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Proceed to use it (dummyTable). Clear it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. But it is working only for csv. not for xlsx. what do i need to modify in the code to make it to work for xlsx files?

Comment: It can be that or a text file. It is the contents from a text formatting standpoint that matters, not the file extension

Comment: Yeah Correct. 
But what do i need to give the values for fields terminated by and optionally enclosed by? 
I tried the below. But it is loading garbage data to the table. 

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\dummy/dummy.xlsx' 
INTO TABLE dummy
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: Cs i would need to see a few rows of the file to import to see why u get garbage and the table structure

Comment: I am really not able to understand why i am getting garbage values. I am using the same code above. Could you please check once. 

Also i doubt the below. xlsx files do no terminate by ','. do i need to change these below values while dealing with xlsx?

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: Place file to import somewhere on web. If that means creating a insensitive data one so be it. Then i will test

Comment: I have uploaded the file and the data screenshot in the below. Could you please check. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5G7Y9UP5Vi3fmpUbmFBcTVobEZSZFdmRUxSYVktaHBNQW0wcVpZMGNtVWV3dk9iT0tSQTQ&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate the mysql queries from excel using PHP.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'query_generator.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("example.xls");
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '101', 'Narendra Modi', 'Cabinet Ministers', 'Personnel, Public Grievances and Pensions, Department of Atomic Energy, Department of Space, All important policy issues and all other portfolios not allocated to any Minister', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '102', 'Rajnath Singh', 'Cabinet Ministers', 'Home Affairs', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '103', 'Sushma Swaraj', 'Cabinet Ministers', 'External Affairs, Overseas Indian Affairs', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '104', 'Arun Jaitley', 'Cabinet Ministers', 'Finance, Corporate Affairs and Defence', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL');
......
```

I have written PHP code for generate all queries from excel with sngle click for our production system